# Is it possible to extract contents of a Cloudwatch log from a subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a lambda that subscribes to a Cloudwatch Log stream. This all works tickety-boo i.e. when the log stream is written to the lambda receives a notification. Now, is there a way of receiving the contents of the log or a section of the log with the notification or do I then have to query the the log stream to garner the information that I need?

Regards

Angus

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Here's how to do it with a Node.js Lambda:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');

exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    // decode input from base64
    var zippedInput = new Buffer.from(input.awslogs.data, 'base64');

    // decompress the input
    zlib.gunzip(zippedInput, function(error, buffer) {
        if (error) { context.fail(error); return; }

        // parse the input from JSON
        var payload = JSON.parse(buffer.toString('utf8'));

        // ignore control messages
        if (payload.messageType === 'CONTROL_MESSAGE') {
            return null;
        }

        // print the timestamp and message of each log event
        payload.logEvents.forEach(function(logEvent) {
            console.log(logEvent.timestamp + ' ' + logEvent.message);
        });
    });
};
```